# Difference between str[0] and str.charAt(0)

Tags: javascript, string

What is the difference between `str[0]` and `str.charAt(0)`? I always access specific character by simply typing `str[i]`, where `i` is the index of the character I want to access (counted from 0), but last week I had good overview of open source JS code, and in every single project I saw, people use `charAt` method.

Is there any difference between those two ways?

Comment: String 101 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 6):

`[]` is a more primitive way of accessing all kind of arrays.

`charAt()` is specific to strings.

You can access the index of any array by using `[]`, but you can only use `charAt()` on a string.

But when it comes to string alone, both are one and the same.

But you should use `charAt()` because, it is well supported in all the major browsers, while the bracket notation will return `undefined` in IE7

Also, the bracket notation is simply accessed, while `charAt()` does some validation and doesn't return `undefined`, but will return an empty string `""`

Comment: Does anybody care about IE7 nowadays, to not consider `[]` over `charAt`?

Answer (score 4):

This

```
""[-4]          // undefined

"".charAt(-4)   // ""
```

You could ensure that the result would be a string.