# What's the difference between string[i] and string.charAt(i) in Java?

Tags: java, string

I've encoutered an error while writing a line like this:

```
String string;
if (Character.isLetter(string[i])) {...}
```

Eclipse tells me that `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String`.

It does not raise the error if I use `string.charAt(i)` though.

My question is: 
**What is the difference between** `string[i]` **and** `string.charAt(i)` **in** `Java`? 
Are there any *delicate* aspects of using one or another?

I've tried to find a solution by myself, but I've encoutered `javascript` version of this problem only. (Example: [Difference between str[0] and str.charAt(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728882/difference-between-str0-and-str-charat0?lq=1))

Comment: if string is array then only you can do string[i].

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is `string`? If it is instance of `String` then Java doesn't support `[i]`. Why do you think it should work? In Java String *contains* array of characters (`char[]`), but it *is not* such array itself and `[index]` can be used only with array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might clear things up for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "my name is Muneeb";
  String[] strarray = str.split(" "); //split on white space.

  for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
     System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
  }

  for(int i=0; i<strarray.length; i++){
     System.out.println(strarray[i]);
  }
}
```

The first output will be:

```
m
y

n
a
m
e

i
s

M
u
n
e
e
b
```

The second output will be:

```
my
name
is
Muneeb
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java a String type is not the same as an array of characters as it is in some languages. It is possible to get an array of characters from a String, but they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `string[i]` is not the *i*th index of the string. Instead, if you had defined `string` as an array (e.g., `String[] string = new String[10]`), then `string[i]` would refer to the *i*th element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

**String[i]** is a the way to access the ith element in **an array of Strings**, please note they are zero-indexed in java like in javascript.

While **string.charAt(i)** is the **ith character in one particular String**. Here again i is zero-indexed.

It's tempting to think that Strings in java are array of characters like many other languages but in fact they are built on top of a char array which is a private member of class String as explained here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248431/2669716

Answer (score 1):

Accessing elements using the `[]` operator only works for arrays. `String`s are not arrays. That means using the `[]` operator on a `String` does not compile.

If you want to *convert* a `String` to a `char[]` array, use the [`toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) method.

```
String s = // ...
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
char firstLetter = chars[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is used to reference an `index` of an `Array`. While a `String` is usually considered to be an `Array` of `char` (`char[]`), you aren't accessing the character array... that method `string.charAt(i)` will access the `Array` to get you the physical character.

Learn more about the String class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

If you had code like:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "..." };
```

You could do:

```
for (int i=0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("String " + String.valueOf(i) + ": " + String.valueOf(stringArray[i]) + ".");
}
```

Hope that helps!